# Storing secrets and credentials securely in GitLab

Tags: version-control, gitlab, gitlab-ci, credentials, hashicorp-vault

I am wondering if it's possible to store credentials like passwords, tokens and keys safely in my GitLab project.

Currently there are a bunch of Java files with some passwords stored in it for testing purposes. However, I don't want to push this information on my repo due to security reasons. I tried using environment variables in the project, but they only seem to work for the .gitlab-ci.yml file.

My question is does anyone use a vault like Hashicorps or Blackbox to encrypt sensitive information?

Thanks

Comment: FWIW GitLab [doesn't mask](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/255186) the secrets from Hashicorp Vault native integration. However, this integration can still be used to a benefit: it's easier to store, rotate and version control the secrets in the Vault and sync them into GitLab's project/group/instance secrets via i.e. TerraForm.

Answer (score 5):

If you are not using environment variables in GitLab, then you are asking if it is possible to store secrets in GitLab. I have not done this myself, but I found this post about it:

https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2018/03/15/safely-storing-secrets-in-git/

The author suggests three ways of storing secrets in git:

- [Blackbox](https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox)
- [git-secret](https://github.com/sobolevn/git-secret)
- [git-crypt](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt)

The author was using BlackBox, but was going to migrate to git-crypt. From a quick look at it, git-crypt looks like something that I could use myself.

Answer (score 5):

You can check out GitLab 12.9 (March 2020) which comes with:

> ### [HashiCorp Vault GitLab CI/CD Managed Application](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/03/22/gitlab-12-9-released/#hashicorp-vault-gitlab-cicd-managed-application)
>
> GitLab wants to make it easy for users to have modern secrets management. We are now offering users the ability to install Vault within a Kubernetes cluster as part of the GitLab CI managed application process.
>
> This will support the secure management of keys, tokens, and other secrets at the project level in a Helm chart installation.

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/applications.html#install-vault-using-gitlab-ci) and [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/9982).

---

See also [GitLab 13.4](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/09/22/gitlab-13-4-released/#use-hashicorp-vault-secrets-in-ci-jobs) (September 2020)

For Premium/Silver only:

> ### Use HashiCorp Vault secrets in CI jobs
>
> In GitLab 12.10, GitLab introduced functionality for GitLab Runner to fetch and inject secrets into CI jobs. GitLab is now expanding the [JWT Vault Authentication method](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/authenticating-with-hashicorp-vault/) by building a new `secrets` syntax in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. This makes it easier for you to configure and use HashiCorp Vault with GitLab.
>
> https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_4/vault_ci.png -- Use HashiCorp Vault secrets in CI jobs
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/28321).

Answer (score 1):

GitLab will soon include a function for securely storing secrets called as [GitLab Secrets Manager](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/architecture/blueprints/secret_manager/)