# Does Gitlab have his own vault?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Does gitlab contain has his own vault where we could store password in local to use them in CICD, i am looking for something equivalent to HashiCorp Vault or Azure Key Vault ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing secrets and credentials securely in GitLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59320750/storing-secrets-and-credentials-securely-in-gitlab)

Comment: Probably a simpler solution would be to just start using project-level CI/CD variables (which are stored AES encrypted)…

Comment: @slath thank you i agree it's a simpler to use this native solution.

Answer (score 0):

I add the variables directly in Gitlab :
Go to project setting > CI/CD > Variables > Expand > Add variable

Comment: Then you can't call it "a secret"

Answer (score 0):

GitLab has an upcoming feature called as [GitLab Secrets Manager](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/architecture/blueprints/secret_manager/) to securely store secrets

Alternatively, you can also source the secrets stored in Vault by HashiCorp, steps are mentioned [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets/) and substitute the build variables during build time